# Return Data from Node Server to Ionic(Angularjs) Client

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I would like to send data from Ionic to Node Server. Then change data with node and return the other data to Ionic.

But I don't now how I can return the data to ionic.

---

Client using Ionic (Angularjs):

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  data: JSON.stringify("Test")
});
```

---

Server node

```
http = require('http');
server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {

  if (req.method == 'POST') {
    console.log("POST");
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
        console.log("Partial body: " + body);
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log("Body: " + body);
    });
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('success');
    res.end('success');
  }else{
    console.log("GET");
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end("success");
  }
});

port = 3000;
host = '127.0.0.1';
server.listen(port, host);
console.log('Listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
```

Log Output from Server

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/svn/nodejs$ node server.js 
Listening at http://127.0.0.1:3000
POST
Partial body: "Test"
Body: "Test"
```

Comment: in client code, the http function must be taking a `callback` that would come with response from the server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
General usage

The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — 
a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request
and returns a promise.

// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

`$http` returns a `promise`. Promise has function `then` whose first two arguments are `success` and `error` callbacks from the server.

Comment: And how must i make the server side code? It's returns any times error.

Comment: Can you put the logs from server side to see what is happening ?

Comment: it might be CORS in local environment, http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/